# Expand background to entire page when focusing on single container with intro.js

Tags: javascript, css, intro.js

I'm using `intro.js` to tour a specific element

```
introJs("#section1").start()
```

Is there any way I can expand the background to the entire page even when focusing on a single element ?

[JSBIN example](http://jsbin.com/covuxafu/1/) (try to activate the tour for the bottom sections)

I've tried overriding `introjs-overlay`

```
.introjs-overlay { 
  width:100%!important; 
  height:100%!important;
  top:0!important;
  left:0!important;
}
```

but setting `top` to 0 pins the overlay section to the top of the page (if not overriden it's sticks to the specified element).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should fix it:

```
.introjs-overlay {
   position: fixed!important;
}
```

Comment: I meant add this to the overrides you already made. Fixed position should make the overlay stick to the window, not to the document.